# What is a good open-source BitTorrent library?

Tags: c, open-source, posix, bittorrent

I am trying to make a BitTorrent client in C and I need a library. What is a good, widely-used open-source BitTorrent library for C? I've found [libbt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libbt/) but the latest version was more than one and a half year ago. I have also tried [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=bittorrent&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1) but there was no C library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Low activity on a project may indicate that it's mature enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer [libTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) in my own projects.

Comment: libTorrent is not a C library. It is a C++ library.

Comment: @DavidTimothyStrauss: Yes I know, but sometimes you have to bite the bullet. I'm not a fan of C++ myself, but then you also have to be pragmatic.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [libtorrent-rasterbar](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/). It's used by the deluge torrent client. I'm not sure if it's the same libtorrent as in datenwolf's answer.

Comment: Well, looks like I **have to** use C++ then :)